# Codename one login form after connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, codenameone

I built a project in Netbeans-Codename one, Java, to connect to a MYSQL database.
Connection and queries work.

My next step should be to make a Login form, with username and password.
"If user and password exist in database, login. 
After login,
Go to next form" (main form.).

I built the "next forms" using the theme features from Codename one.
The main file just connects to database.
According to the code i am about to give, how can i progress it to make a login form? 
Is there any relevant tutorial?

-I used the "sign in" demo, but i think it is just for the sign in template.
-I used the "responsive sign-in form",
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-gui-builder-autolayout-signin-form-responsive.html
but i want to progress further than that, connect according to database.

dbconnect.java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public DBConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

// host credentials, username, password.

```
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4/dt1","user1","pass1");
            st = con.createStatement();





        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Error "+ex);
        }

        }

    public void getData() {

        try{

            String query = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from Database");
            while(rs.next())  {
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String title = rs.getString("age");
                System.out.println("Name: "+ name + "Age: " + age);


            }         
        }


        catch(SQLException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error2 "+ex);         
        }          
    }           
    }
```

Comment: Is this server code? You can't connect to mysql from the device as it doesn't support JDBC and even if it did you wouldn't want to connect to a database via an unreliable operator network

Comment: I was able to connect to mysql, and do select queries. I want to create a login form according to this database.

Comment: Is this server code or is this code intended for the device? Notice that if you got this to work on the simulator then you've made a mistake and it won't work on the device.

Comment: Edit:
It is the code intended for the device, made in java. It works in the simulator, in a separate project. I am trying to connect it with codename one.

 I tried connecting in the database, after i put this java package in the codename one device, with the rest of my application. It displays errors according to Jdbc.
How do i do the same in the device?

If i do not find a solution, i will do a separate question for this.

Comment: This code won't work on the device, see my answer to the other question. If you want to access the native API's in the device you can use native interfaces but it's still a bad idea to open a database connection from a device